# Where are the memory leaks in my for ... in loop with addObject 

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

There seem to be some memory leaks in the following loop:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(SomeClass *someObject in array2){    //has already been populated;
    if (someObject.field == desiredValue){
        [array1 addObject:someObject];
    }
}
//EDIT:
//use array1 for very secret operations
[array1 release];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: why do you say it leaks memory? are you sure its not some other part of your code?

Comment: Do you release array2? The problem may be there.

Comment: If i said i am sure i would be lying. but that's where the Leaks Instrument guides me to when i double click on the leak report. Could be wrong, i am kinda new to debugging.

Comment: Could it be the objects of array2 that are leaking (e.g. added to array2 but never released afterwards)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you releasing all your retained properties in SomeClass of yours? Make sure in dealloc release all retained properties.. Make sure your SomeClass is leak free..

Comment: Nice thought, but the leak still remains. Nonetheless fixed the one that was crashing my app, so it's workable again but still that red line in Leaks is annoying.

Comment: Can you recreate the leak with some custom SomeClass (If you cant post your original class) and post the code...As far as I see your code is perfect and leak free..

Comment: I will, but i got a boss-like figure breathing on my neck at the moment so since it's working i'll come back to it later :) thanks for your time though!